Oracle 10g impdp without REMAP_TABLE
I have the following question, and I don't know what the best way to proceed would be. I have an Oracle 10g server, and a schema table has become unusable due to operator failures. So I had to do a recovery, of a snap I had from the server.
The first procedure was to recover the entire server from a few previous days and since there is recovering the table with an expdp, this has been the order implemented:

expdp schema/password tables=mytable directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=mytable.dump logfile=expdpmytable.log

So far so good, I'm about to copy the dump to the original server with the damaged table, and here's my problem. Since the current damaged table cannot be overwritten and I have to create an additional table i.e. mytable_restore.
I was going to execute the following order:

impdp schema/password directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=mytable.dump logfile=impdpmytable.log REMAP_TABLE= schema.mytable:mytable_restore

Well here I found the problem in version 10g the REMAP_TABLE parameter is not available so I cannot import it that way.
This is my current point, I want to ask the community for help on what would be the best path to follow having the following problems.
A solution would be to create a new schema and dump the table, and then try to pass it to the other schema? Would any example be helpful to me, or what would be the best option to take?

In the end I chose to import the schema, and once imported copy the table to the old schema.
But I have encountered another problem, the following process is extremely slow:

Processing SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX

I may ask a new question on this topic, I don't know if it is a problem with the 10g versions.
